# Why is my user being created through Rails console, but no email attribute being stored in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I am following the Rails tutorial at railstutorial.org. Currently I am about to finish Chapter 6. When I go to create a new user through rails console, the user is created in the database but the email attribute is set to `nil`. When I assign directly an email to the user, it is changed in memory but when I go and save it through the `save` method to persist it in the database, the following error shows up:

```
User Exists (0.2ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) AND "users"."id" != ? LIMIT
```

Why does it save in memory but not in the database?

I tried remigrating the database with `rails db:migrate`. And deleting all users in case there were some other users with the same email (as there is a constraint or validation rule for the uniqueness of the mail). Still get the same error.

This is the `schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_13_035531) do

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end

end
```

This is the user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50} 
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: One of your model validations is the uniqueness of the email

Comment: Yes, it is. But even when I delete all created users. It still throws the error. Does it store the object in memory and somehow collides with the database validation rules? Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: How are you creating the user in the console? What code are you using? It should be something like `User.create(name: 'Some Name', email: 'test@email.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')`. Also, does the create action in your users controller look like?

Comment: I have used `user = User.new( name: "Some name", email: "some@email.com", password: "securepasssword", password_confirmation: "securepassword")`

Then I have saved that user with `user.save` and then is where it throws the mentioned error.

Comment: It's not the error, it's just SQL log :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of reading, it turned out that I had just to `rails db:migrate:reset`. And it worked. Apparently, there was still a non unique mail or something. I didn't get to understand fully why did the error happened and if someone can give me a better insight of the inner functioning of the rails framework would be much appreciated as I am new to this too. Thank your for your kind support.